# Is inversion globally well defined on complete anaytic manifods

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a complete analytic Riemannian manifold. Let $p$ be a point in $M$ and let $u,v$ be tangents at $p$ such that $\exp(u)=\exp(v)$, must we have $\exp(-u)=\exp(-v)$ ?

This property seems to good to be true, so I would not be surprised if there is a counterexample ,on the other hand I don't know any counterexamples.

Comment: Without the analyticity it's certainly not true. I'm going to bet it's true, but I don't yet see a proof.

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I think I already know a counterexample in the smooth case by modifying the metric by a bump function

Comment: is a 1 sheeted hyperboloid an analytic Riemannisn manifold?

Comment: @Jason Devito I would expect it to be analytic. Does it give a counterexample?

Comment: By analytic, I meant that the pullback of the metric in Normal coordinates has analytic components as a tensor field

Comment: @Jason Sarcasm duly noted. Breaking symmetry by starting off the equator. I guess the circular paraboloid works just as well. Shame on me!

Comment: @TedShifrin:  Honestly, I wasn't trying to be sarcastic - I only think on the smooth category, so i genuinely wasn't sure about my question.  But you're right that I was thinking of breaking symmetry by starting away from the center circle.

Comment: @Jason If the submanifold is given as the zero set of a real analytic function, then the analytic implicit function theorem gives analytic charts. In this case, we can do it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you all for your help